# Combining/updating parameters from multiple estimations

Tags: regression, estimation, regression-coefficients

Take a simple example of performing two independent linear regressions on a set of x-y data, in the form of y = mx + b, each using half of the data. I will obtain two separate estimates for m1, b1, m2, and b2. I could then obtain how confident I am in estimating each of the parameters. I wish to find the global m and b.

My question is, how would I update my first estimate (m1, b1) with my latter estimate result (m2, b2)? Assuming I no longer have access to the full dataset and am only left with the estimates and their confidence? If these were independent parameters, I can update them using Bayesian Inference (ie. weighted average based on the confidences), but can I look at m and b independently? For example, if I manage to estimate m1 and b2 with 100% confidence, and m2 and b1 with 0%, then taking m1x + b2 as the best model would be wrong?

In actuality, this problem arises from performing online parameter estimations. Given a polynomial model structure with unknown coefficients to be estimated, a new set of parameters are estimated at each interval and updates the prior. However, I struggle to figure out how to merge these coefficients with the prior since mix-and-matching the coefficients independently would result in a Frankenstein of an equation that resembles nothing.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Kalman filter was born to be applied to sensor synthesis.  If you know the estimate and covariance for each expression, it becomes straightforward to integrate them.  One method for restricting impact of pathological cases is momentum, also expressible as EWMA.  It is a bit messy with the artificial parameters, but the approach can yield decent results.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The problem I present is indeed with artificial parameters. For a typical state estimation problem using Kalman filter, each state can be estimated independently and updated as such. But for coefficients of a polynomial, there's no real physical relationship between them to tie them through system dynamics, and yet it somehow feels wrong to treat them as separate entities.

Comment: Classic polynomial is still linear and can fit inside of a kalman filter. The model update covariance is non-linear. There’s some good textbook ways around that including extended, ensemble, and flow filters.